# Materialize CSS default browser for radio input

Tags: html, css, materialize

I want to use browser default radio input instead of materialize css custom radio input. How to do that?

This line of codes will automatically use materialize css custom radio input instead of browser default:

```
<label>
    <input name="pay-type" value="mc" type="radio" checked />
    <span>Emoney</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Materialize CSS and the style is applied on all elements on the page. You can create custom class for this particular input element and apply browser default class to it.

```
<label>
    <input class="custom" name="pay-type" value="mc" type="radio" checked />
    <span>Emoney</span>
</label>

.custom {
    background-color: initial;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-appearance: radio;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 3px 3px 0px 5px;
    padding: initial;
    border: initial;
}
```

Try this and let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>index</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      background: #e6e6e6;
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    }
    
    .container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .control-group {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      background: #fff;
      text-align: left;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      padding: 20px;
      width: 180px;
      height: 180px;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    
    .control {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    .control input {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .control__indicator {
      position: absolute;
      top: 2px;
      left: 0;
      height: 20px;
      width: 20px;
      background: #e6e6e6;
    }
    
    .control--radio .control__indicator {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    
    .control:hover input~.control__indicator,
    .control input:focus~.control__indicator {
      background: #ccc;
    }
    
    .control input:checked~.control__indicator {
      background: #2aa1c0;
    }
    
    .control:hover input:not([disabled]):checked~.control__indicator,
    .control input:checked:focus~.control__indicator {
      background: #0e647d;
    }
    
    .control__indicator:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
    }
    
    .control input:checked~.control__indicator:after {
      display: block;
    }
    
    .control--checkbox .control__indicator:after {
      left: 8px;
      top: 4px;
      width: 3px;
      height: 8px;
      border: solid #fff;
      border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    .control--radio .control__indicator:after {
      left: 7px;
      top: 7px;
      height: 6px;
      width: 6px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: #fff;
    }
    
    .select {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .select select {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      outline: 0;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
      background: #e6e6e6;
      color: #7b7b7b;
      appearance: none;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
    }
    
    .select select::-ms-expand {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .select select:hover,
    .select select:focus {
      color: #000;
      background: #ccc;
    }
    
    .select__arrow {
      position: absolute;
      top: 16px;
      right: 15px;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      pointer-events: none;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 8px 5px 0 5px;
      border-color: #7b7b7b transparent transparent transparent;
    }
    
    .select select:hover~.select__arrow,
    .select select:focus~.select__arrow {
      border-top-color: #000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control control--radio">First radio
                <input type="radio" name="radio" checked="checked" />
                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
      <label class="control control--radio">Second radio
                <input type="radio" name="radio" />
                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
            </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> go and check here [Custom Design of radio button](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_custom_radio)